# Reply Mail Management - Custom Email Body

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, dynamic, email-studio

I am trying to insert the code %%=ContentBlockbyId("370")=%% on my RMM body, but when I got the RMM message SFMC it isn't translated the AMPScript and I am receiving an email with the message `%%=ContentBlockbyId("370")=%%`

This is AMPscript it's very simple:

`%%[if not empty(Firstname) then]%%
Hello %%Firstname%%,%%[else]%%
Hello,%%[endif]%% 
some other text`

Do you know what's wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Standard Reply Mails are static content only. To personalize reply mails you first have to open a case to have support enable "dynamic reply mail management", which is usually free.

Once this is activated you get a new configuration option in the reply mail settings to select a Triggered Send Definition.

The email you use in the triggered send works with all the personalization features you already know.

Comment: Thanks Stephan, I will do it.

Answer (score 1):

I think the content block is being pulled as simple text. To execute the content within the content block you'd need to treat it as content.

You'd add a new function around your ContentBlockbyId function.

Try:

> `%%=TreatAsContent(ContentBlockbyId("370"))=%%`

Reference:

- [TreatAsContent](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/treatascontent.htm)

Comment: I Brad I tried to use %%=TreatAsContent(ContentBlockbyId("370"))=%%, but didn't work, I guess that RMM on SFMC doesn't accept AMPScript in the body.